# Can I specify a formatter for XML in Eclipse?

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt

I know there is a formatter option under code style for Java code, which affects how Eclipse formats your code when you ctrl + shift + f.

However, using this shortcut in an XML/XSL document, it formats it in a way that I don't like and isn't very readable.

Can I override this behavior somehow for the oXygen plugin, or even  the default XML editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Eclipse XML editor, all you get is in Preferences > XML > XML Files > Editor. What's there is not as rich as the Java formatter, but I've found it to be sufficient.

Comment: My problem is it keeps breaking apart one liners like a <button> tag onto 2 lines (annoying) or worse yet, it breaks text onto multiple lines which affects the actual page display.

Comment: Have you set the **Line Width** on that preferences page to something really large? Have you un-checked the option to **Split multiple attributes**?

Comment: Didn't notice line width.  Looks like that should do the trick, actually.  Thanks.